# What do I need to use a Nikon El Nikkor 50mm 2.8 enlarging lens with a Canon 5D mark II?

Tags: lens, adapter

How can I connect the Nikon el-nikkor 50mm f2.8 enlarging lens to my Canon 5D Mark II? What adapter / reversing ring do I need?

Comment: Are you going to be using this on a bellows?

Comment: Wiki says that lens is an M39 mount. I googled _M39 to EOS adaptor_ and a few results came up. I'm sure you could get it to fit with something from there but you might get infinity problems. But then again, you might anyway with a specialised device as it's designed for [photographic enlarging.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photographic_enlarger)

Comment: Did you get an answer to this?

Answer (score 2):

The lens in question is designed for a photographic enlarger which is used during film printing to enlarge the negative onto the photo paper. However, there are places that will, in fact, make adapters one of which is [Zörk Film and Phototechnic](http://www.zoerk.com/pages/products.htm) in Germany. They don't really list the product detail, but if you contact them, they can probably let you know if it is possible. I believe the Multi-Focus System uses enlarger lenses.

For interest, Nikon talks about this lens here: http://www.nikon.com/about/feelnikon/recollections/r15_e/index.htm

Answer (score 1):

I have both the Nikon el-nikkor 50mm f2.8 enlarging lens and a Canon 5D Mark II. I have two ways. 
1) Mount the lens on a Canon body cap and use Canon extension tubes to mount the lens. The lens aperture ring is hard to turn, so the mounting to the body cap must be good to avoid the lens twisting off when the aperture is changed. 
2) The way I do it is mount a Canon to Pentax screw adapter to the camera, put on Pentax extension tubes (much cheaper than Canon), then, to the extension tubes, I mount the reversed Nikkor with an adapter that I modified. This adapter is part of an old Pentax slide copier that I removed and put in set screws to hold enlarging lenses. But, you could reverse mount the lens to a Pentax body cap, using tape, glue, screws, or the like.
~Bob~